# How to create nested case class with lens-like approach

Tags: scala, shapeless

It's really nice to "modify" fields with lenses:

```
case class Address(street : String, city : String, postcode : String)
case class Person(name : String, age : Int, address : Address)

val nameLens     = lens[Person] >> 'name
val ageLens      = lens[Person] >> 'age
val addressLens  = lens[Person] >> 'address
val streetLens   = lens[Person] >> 'address >> 'street
val cityLens     = lens[Person] >> 'address >> 'city
val postcodeLens = lens[Person] >> 'address >> 'postcode


val person = Person("Joe Grey", 37, Address("Southover Street", "Brighton", "BN2 9UA"))

val person2 = ageLens.modify(person)(_ + 1)
```

But it would be really nice to have ability to create whole classes/records with that syntax, like:

```
val personRaw: String :: Int :: (String :: String :: String :: HNil) :: HNil = 
   ('address >> 'postcode ->> "BN2 9UA") :: 
   ('name ->> "Joe Grey") ::
   ('age ->> 37) ::
   ('address >> 'street ->> "Southover Street") ::
   ('address >> 'city ->> "Brighton") ::   
   HNil

val personGen = Generic[Person]
personGen.from(personRaw) //here is type check
```

I didn't find such in shapeless. Is there any (typesafe) way to achieve something similar?

P.S. Why do I need that? I'm planning to have a large set of such rules, so it could be easy to find where every value of our big entity came from. So my current guess is to write a macro to process such records, but maybe someone already did this.